# Plural Usage- 10 Travelers Who Bought A One-Way Ticket And Began A New Life

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I came across this title today

> 10 Travelers Who Bought A One-Way Ticket And Began A New Life

I was confused about the usage of singular nouns "a one-way ticket" and "a new life" as the subject is clearly plural. Aren't these words supposed to be plural as well, following the subject-object agreement?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

> 10 Travelers, **each of whom** bought A One-Way Ticket And Began A New Life.

You could have made them plural:

> 10 Travelers Who Bought One-Way Tickets And Began New Lives

but it is not necessary. Actually, "one-way ticket" is used figuratively. My guess is that it means going in a new lifestyle direction and not looking back, rather than buying a physical ticket. In that case, plural would not be appropriate.

Comment: yes, a native listener will resolve the problem by (so to speak) mentally inserting an 'each' after 'who'.

Comment: @user3169 Thank you. But what about new life part? I don't have to pluralize "new life" as well?

Comment: "A New Life" is also figurative, similar to "[*starting over*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/start+over)".

Comment: What do you mean exactly by figurative? Do you mean that it's like an idiom?

Comment: It means not literal word for word. A one-way plane ticket vs. taking some action that can't be undone. Idioms usually hold a set meaning beyond the individual words' definitions.

Answer (score 0):

This usage isn't allowed in formal English, but it's common to see it, especially in headlines. [Headline English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) allows this kind of construction where the word "who" is used as a  a shorter way to indicate "each of whom," as mentioned in @user3169's answer.

Comment: Oh ok. So in formal English, I will have to make them plural, right?

Comment: @vivaldi You can, but if you make them plural it will change the meaning a bit. If you want to keep the current meaning in formal English, you can just add "each": "Here are ten travelers who each bought a one-way ticket and began a new life."